# Which folders and files of Laravel we dont need on production (Web) server?

Tags: laravel, file, server, upload

Have done some website on Laravel framework. I did it on local server and now started to upload it on production (Web) server.

I realize, that Laravel have many and many files. I wonder, if I need to have them all on production server?

So want to ask, if some folders or files I dont need to upload on Web server? Have someone experience with it? Because I didnt find any quality information about it.

Thanks!

Comment: You do mean `git` right? Your local or development version of your website shouldn't differ from your production server.

Comment: @dbf This is just wrong. Development versions and productions versions are almost never the same. Production versions are optimized for production and gracefully handle failures without revealing configuration information to the public.

Comment: @Nilpo "This is just wrong", no it's not. Just try and read my  comment again more slowly.

Comment: @dbf I've read it many times. I stand by my comment. If both versions were the same, there would be no need for development branching and production branching because they would always be the same.

Comment: @Nilpo yes, but I didn’t argue against any of your arguments nor did you counter any of mine. Of course there is a different between any development environment and production, but I do hope you don’t mean it differs in code. The same base should distinguish between environments, but your code remains the same, e.g “env = development” will produce a different behavior, but never touches your base if env would be set to production.

Comment: @dbf I absolutely mean that development code and production code should be different. Of course they are. You don't leave development services lingering in production code as they could expose vulnerabilities. Production code is often minified or even compiled. So yes, they are distinctly different code bases depending on your project workflow

Comment: @Nilpo Naaah .. we're not getting anywhere here :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the deployment [guide here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/deployment), for general information how to move to production.

Also you can take a look at the `.gitignore` file in the project root. Everything that is listed here isn't supposed to move to production.

This includes these files and directories:

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
.env.backup
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
```

Especially the `node_modules` and `vendor` directory will contain lot's and lot's of files and libraries.

The contents of the `vendor` directory are described by `composer.json / composer.lock` These can also be installed directly on the production server by running:

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
```

The `node_modules` directory is usually just needed on the develop server. It's contents are described by `package.json / package.lock`. Once you build your final assets by running

```
npm run production
```

it's sufficient to upload the minified output files of that command (mostly .css and .js files) to production.

Comment: does this answer your question? Or do you need clarification?

Comment: `"Everything that is listed here isn't supposed to move to production."` Is not correct. `.env` is needed as well as `vendor/**`.

Comment: Of course it's needed! But what I meant is, that you are not supposed to transfer exact copies of those files to production. You put a production version of your .env file on the production server and you use the composer commands as stated in my answer above (have you fully read it?) to download only the needed vendor/ dependencies for production. That's why you shouldn't directly upload those files ;)

Comment: This should not have a -1. This IS the correct answer and should be accepted.